# Measure noise level/sound quality by comparision

Tags: audio, compare, wav, noise

Ok, so I go this VoIP service and need a simple test of the sound quality transmitted. 2 VMs will "talk", and the tests will be done by a third computer. We have the record of the sound spoken and another recording of the sound received(.wav). The testing computer receives both files (pre and pos transmission, pos-transmission should have a little noise or errors) and need to compare the sound quality between then. The only relevant info, would be an output saying how good the quality is at he receiver end. (something like 0.0 - 1.0 score) I'm having a lot of trouble comparing the 2 sounds recorded, any insight and help would be great. Oh yeah, this must be automatized, so there is no one to listen both records and say how bad one of then is. The computer should be able to determine the final quality.

Sorry for any mistake, English is not my first language, and thanks again for any possible help.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very interesting, but unfortunately you have thin chances of getting a perfect solution since it is an open problem. You might be interested in [PESQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESQ) (Perceptual Evaluation of Speech Quality) (implementation at: http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-P.862-200102-I/en)

Comment: This was actually incredibly useful, I will give a look at the files (2004) and see what I can use, but basically the Full Reference describes perfectly what I need to implement.

Comment: Sadly the implementation is totally over my capacities, couldn't make it work or figure how to use it with my own sound samples.

Comment: I will see if I can put up something later today, or tomorrow.

Comment: Can you share some audio samples ?